# Bin data by x and y columns, and output the mean of a third column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have three columns like so:

```
x     y     Value
0.5   0.5     3
2.3   1.2     5
2.7   1.6     10
3.3   4.1     4
3.5   4.2     6
3.8   4.6     8
```

I want to bin columns x and y and find the mean of column Value. ie. the average would be found between points (3,3) and (4,4), which would equal to 4+6+8/3 = 6. So the output should be like so:

```
x_bin     y_bin      mean_value
 0, 1      0, 1        3
 0, 1      1, 2        0
 0, 1      2, 3        0
 0, 1      3, 4        0
 1, 2      0, 1        0
 1, 2      1, 2        0
 1, 2      2, 3        0
 1, 2      3, 4        0
 2, 3      0, 1        0  
 2, 3      1, 2        7.5
 2, 3      2, 3        0
 2, 3      3, 4        0
 3, 4      0, 1        0 
 3, 4      1, 2        0
 3, 4      2, 3        0
 3, 4      3, 4        6
```

Ideally, I would like the output in a format where I could plot this as a heatmap grid.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`np.histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.2/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) is numpy's function to bin 2D data. By default, the result counts the points into each bin. With the `weights=` parameter, the points are weighted, and those weights are summed.  Dividing the summed weights by the counts gives the means.

Seaborn's [`sns.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) can display these means and automatically annotate the cell values.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = [0.5, 2.3, 2.7, 3.3, 3.5, 3.8]
y = [0.5, 1.2, 1.6, 4.1, 4.2, 4.6]
value = [3, 5, 10, 4, 6, 8]
bins = (np.arange(6), np.arange(6))
sums, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins, weights=value)
counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)
with  np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):  # divide 0 by 0 results in NaN
    means = sums / counts
sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.heatmap(means, annot=True, fmt='.1f', cmap='turbo', vmin=0, vmax=10, square=True,
                cbar=True, cbar_kws={'ticks': np.arange(11)})
ax.set_xticks(range(len(bins[0])))
ax.set_xticklabels(bins[0])
ax.set_yticks(range(len(bins[1])))
ax.set_yticklabels(bins[1])
ax.tick_params(labelrotation=0)
ax.grid(axis='both', color='0.3', clip_on=False)
ax.set_axisbelow(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The image shows the plots for:

- `bins = (np.arange(6), np.arange(6))`,
- `bins = ([0, 2, 4, 6], [0, 2, 4, 6])` and
- `bins = (np.arange(0, 5.0001, 0.5), np.arange(0, 5.0001, 0.5))`

[image: sns.heatmap with means of 2d weights]

Comment: Thanks JohanC, that really helps. If I was to bin the values into smaller groups what would I change in the code, eg. if I wanted to find the mean of the 2 x 2 grids

Comment: I updated the answer using `ax.set_xticks(range(len(bins[0])))`, using another colormap and showing the effect of the bins.